# RestKit Object Mapping did not mapping my object

Tags: objective-c, restkit

```
{"avatar_30":"url", 
"id": 81, 
"name": "\u674e\u5f3a"
}
```

I have my Profile Class.

```
@interface Profile: NSObject{
    NSNumber* _identifier;
    NSString* _name;
    NSString* _avatar_30;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* avatar_30;
@end

@implementation Profile

@synthesize identifier=_identifier;
@synthesize name=_name;
@synthesize avatar_30 = _avatar_30;
```

And then I build my manager and get mapping for Profile Class like these:
in AppDelegate.h
    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder 
    in AppDelegate.m

```
RKObjectMapping* profileMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Profile class]];
    [profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"identifier"];
    [profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [profileMapping mapKeyPath:@"avatar_30" toAttribute:@"avatar_30"];

    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:_baseURL];
    //[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:profileMapping forKeyPath:@"%@"];
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/v2/userinfo/100/" objectMapping:profileMapping delegate:self];
```

I can get the jason correctly, however the profile can not be mapped.

```
Got a JSON response back from GET!
2012-04-10 17:47:33.480 Base_01[5714:14603] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:198 Found        directly configured object mapping, creating temporary mapping provider for keyPath '%@'
2012-04-10 17:47:33.482 Base_01[5714:fb03] Load collection of Profiles: (
)
```

Could any have any idea for this problem ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For your profileMapping test to add this line : [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:profileMapping forKeyPath:@"profile"];

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects{
```

are there any objects in the "objects" array?

This should contain all your Profile objects.